# How to extract only text from addresses in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains a column named "Address". I want to extract text such as Street name, Building and any thing that does not contain numbers and special characters. The number can be anywhere in the address in the beginning, end and middle. The table example is given below:

```
Address
5734 N STATE RD
111 ARROWHEAD DR
ROBINSON ST 817 
7569 MILL ST
196 MINNETONKA DR
2780 RAY BLVD
8257 MEADOWWOOD DR
N COSTNER CT SE 6118 
810 S FRONT ST
7950 US HIGHWAY 27 S APT 4B 
17248 SANDGATE PL
7950 US HIGHWAY 27 S APT 1B 
17248 SANDGATE PL
23984 HOOKER DR
5272 OAKHILL DR
15528 CLOVERNOOK DR APT 2A
110 E ELM ST
4534 DOWNING ST
CAMP TANUGA RD NE 6385 
220 S MUENSCHER ST
645 N 2ND ST
2217 BUCKWHEAT LN
405 SUNSET LN
KING RD 11576 
1015 HOMECREST AVE
APPLE LN 143
```

The result table should look like as below that contains only text.:

```
Address
N STATE RD
ARROWHEAD DR
ROBINSON ST
MILL ST
MINNETONKA DR
RAY BLVD
MEADOWWOOD DR
N COSTNER CT SE
S FRONT ST
US HIGHWAY S APT B
SANDGATE PL
OHN ST
HOOKER DR
OAKHILL DR
CLOVERNOOK DR APT A
E ELM ST
DOWNING ST
CAMP TANUGA RD NE
S MUENSCHER ST
N ND ST
BUCKWHEAT LN
SUNSET LN
KING RD
HOMECREST AVE
APPLE LN
```

I got the following code from the web

```
declare @strValue VARCHAR(256) = 'ascdh12356.gs79hks@@@sdkj' 
declare @CharPos INT
set @CharPos = patindex('%[0-9]%', @strValue)
while @CharPos > 0
begin
set @strValue = stuff(@strValue, @CharPos, 1, '')
set @CharPos = patindex('%[0-9]%', @strValue )
end
select @strValue

Result: ascdh.gshks@@@sdkj
```

It can be seen that it is working perfectly fine. However, I am not sure how to use it with SQL table. Kindly use the table as reference and guide me how to format the query or show me an alternative way to get the result. Thanks

Comment: Create a user-defined function out of it and you can call that.

Comment: What type of database are you using?  Are you accounting for the fact that numbers sometimes appear as part of the "text" bit of an address i.e. 123 67TH ST?  Should that return 67TH ST or just TH ST?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It should return TH ST for 67TH ST.

Comment: What SQL database system are you using? What version? I'm guessing SQL server, but knowing the version would be handy

Comment: Hi, I am using SQL server 13. Thanks

Comment: Gordon Linoff   Hi, Thanks. I am not good with SQL. Could you guide how to create a user_defined function in SQL.

Comment: How to create a function is al explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Thank you so much Luuk. I am able to create user_defined function. Thank you again for your help. It works like magic. :)